# MLJ: selecting rows and columns for training in evaluate

Tags: machine-learning, julia, regression

I want to implement a kernel ridge regression that also works within MLJ. Moreover, I want to have the option to use either feature vectors or a predefined kernel matrix as in Python [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.html).

When I run this code

```
const MMI = MLJModelInterface    
MMI.@mlj_model mutable struct KRRModel <: MLJModelInterface.Deterministic
        mu::Float64 = 1::(_ > 0)
        kernel::String = "linear"
end
function MMI.fit(m::KRRModel,verbosity::Int,K,y)
    K = MLJBase.matrix(K)
    fitresult = inv(K+m.mu*I)*y
    cache = nothing
    report = nothing
    return (fitresult,cache,report)
end

   
N = 10
K = randn(N,N)
K = K*K
a = randn(N)
y = K*a + 0.2*randn(N)
m = KRRModel()
kregressor = machine(m,K,y)
cv = CV(; nfolds=6,  shuffle=nothing, rng=nothing)
evaluate!(kregressor, resampling=cv, measure=rms, verbosity=1)
```

the `evaluate!` function evaluates the machine on different subsets of rows of K. Due to the Representer Theorem, a kernel ridge regression has a number of nonzero coefficients equal to the number of samples. Hence, a reduced size matrix `K[train_rows,train_rows]` can be used instead of `K[train_rows,:]`.

To denote I'm using a kernel matrix I'd set `m.kernel = ""` . How do I make `evaluate!` select the columns as well as the rows to form a smaller matrix when `m.kernel = ""`?

This is my first time using MLJ and I'd like to make as few modifications as possible.

Comment: I guess I could easily do this by manually calling fit! with the smaller kernel matrix, but I want to get the whole MLJ pipeline working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/mlj-selecting-rows-and-columns-for-training-in-evaluate-for-kernel-regression/52832/3) I got on the Julia Discourse from @ablaom

> The intended use of `evaluate!` is to estimate the generalisation error
> associated with some supervised learning model, by subsampling
> observations, as in cross-validation, a common use-case. I’m afraid
> there is no natural way for `evaluate!` do feature subsampling.
>
> https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/MLJ.jl/dev/evaluating_model_performance/
>
> FYI: There is a version of kernel regression implementing the MLJ
> model interface, namely kernel partial least squares regression from
> the package https://github.com/lalvim/PartialLeastSquaresRegressor.jl